# subview animation in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am using below code to show hide my subview:

```
    [self.view addSubview:selectorView];
[selectorView setFrame:CGRectOffset([selectorView frame], 0, -selectorView.frame.size.height)];
viewVisible = NO;

- (IBAction)onButtonClick:(id)sender {
[self showHideView]; // Show and hide our imageView in an animated fashion}

- (void)showHideView {  
if (viewVisible) { // If our imageView is on screen hide the view
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateImageOff" context:NULL]; // Begin animation
    [selectorView setFrame:CGRectOffset([selectorView frame], 0, -selectorView.frame.size.height)]; // Move imageView off screen
    [UIView commitAnimations]; // End animations
    viewVisible = NO;
    [showHideButton setTitle:@"Show" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; // Change button title to "Show"
} else { // if our imageView is off screen show the view
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateImageOn" context:NULL]; // Begin animation
    [selectorView setFrame:CGRectOffset([selectorView frame], 0, selectorView.frame.size.height)]; // Move imageView on screen
    [UIView commitAnimations]; // End animations
    viewVisible = YES;
    [showHideButton setTitle:@"Hide" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; // Change button title to "Hide"

}}
```

How can I set the subview Y-axis value in this code because when the subview gets on the screen it hides my screen header bar And I am using a button to show/hide the subview, I also want to animate that button so that when the button is clicked, button's position should also be changed along Y-axis.

Here are the screenshots for what I want

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to bring your your header view to front in the MainView:

```
     [self.view bringSubviewToFront:headerView];
```

And the image button animation you can do this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    CGFloat degrees = 180;
    CGAffineTransform transform = 
    CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degrees/180 * 3.14);
    imageButton.transform = transform;

}];
```